# Loading data using jQuery and an image map

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I have the map of USA and I want to display the content of a htm page depending on the state clicked. For example: if I click on the New York state, then the page to be loaded is ny.htm.
How can I get this done in jQuery?

Comment: it would help if we had the html for the map of the USA

Comment: the dreaded image map....... I recommend taking a look at http://raphaeljs.com/ for doing something like this, mainly this example http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Comment: Loktar -  that is a good example. Thanks!

Comment: This is the solution to my question above:

    $("map *").click(function () {
        var stateId = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#state-data").load(stateId + ".htm");
    }); 

the id for each coordinate is the state abbreviation and the htm page for each state is the abbreviation with the extension .htm

Now I can load a page for each state.

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html